# WF and Hierarchical State Machines

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Searching bing and google I'm finding some, but surprisingly little information about state charts in relation to windows work flow.  The only clear answer I've derived is "yes it can handle state charts, and here is a tutorial."

But what I'm trying to determine is:

- Does it support hierarchical state machines as richly as [Samek's QHSM](http://www.hessmer.org/dev/qhsm/).  For example:

  - Can it handle a transition from a nested state to another nested state, where all entry and exit events are correctly fired?
  - Does it handle or facilitate transition to history?
- What drawbacks, if any, should I consider about using WF for (hierarchical) state charts?
- How has the story changed, if any, from WF4 to WF45?

I am not concerned if WF (hierarchical) state charts are much slower than Samek's.  It is only the expressiveness I'm curious about.