# WF - Share Transition across all States

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4.5

Does Windows Workflow Foundation 4.0+ and more specifically its State Machine workflow have the concept of shared events/transitions across all states within a workflow? Also known as a Hierarchical State Machine.

This was possible in WF 3.5 [as proven here, if you scroll to the bottom](http://odetocode.com/articles/460.aspx).

I really can't find anyway to implement this kind of behavior, and I'm looking to upgrade an exiting WF 3.5 system.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846019/wf-and-hierarchical-state-machines) although its got a larger scope, and no answers.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example I can see that plenty of classes and interfaces used in that article are obsolete and you should not use them in your future projects:

[EventDrivenActivity Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/system.workflow.activities.eventdrivenactivity(v=vs.110).aspx)

[HandleExternalEventActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.handleexternaleventactivity(v=vs.110).aspx)

[WebServiceInputActivity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.webserviceinputactivity(v=vs.110).aspx)

....

Below are the WF4 alternatives for your problem:

1. Arguments
2. [Bookmarks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489442(v=vs.110).aspx) : allows you to do event-driven communication to an activity within a workflow from outside by the help of WF runtime as the channel of communication.

[Resuming a pending workflow is now managed using a Bookmark object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489410(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks @MHOOS, I'm not talking about actually implementing old code as is, I'm talking about the design options that used to be available and building a similar system that uses those options (Hierarchical State Machines) in a newer version of WF within the state machine context. In the example I linked to, K. Scott Allen (@OdeToCode) talks about adding an On Bug Closed event, that can be fired at any time, no matter which state the machine is currently in. I can't seem to find a way to implement that behavior in WF4.